# jInvertScroll for horizontal scrolling goes the wrong direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried using jInvertScroll so that my header background image would scroll to the left while scrolling down and then the whole site continues as a normal webpage when it has reached the right border of the image. 
Unfortunately, now the picture somehow scrolls to the right and I have no idea why.

I tried switching around my html and mainly my css (e.g. top:0 instead of bottom:0 etc.). As I'm just starting to learn js I'm not able to fix or modify the javascript part of the thing.

HTML with embedded javascript:

```
     <body>
        <header>
            <div class="background scroll">
                <img src="media/header.png" alt="background image" class="background_img"/>
            </div>
        </header> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascript/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascript/jquery.jInvertScroll.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
        var elem = $.jInvertScroll(['.scroll'],        // an array containing the selector(s) for the elements you want to animate
            {
            height: 3000,  
            onScroll: function(percent) {   
                console.log(percent);
            }
        });
        $(window).resize(function() {
          if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            elem.destroy();
          }
          else {
            elem.reinitialize();
          }
        });
    }(jQuery));
        </script>    
    </body>
```

corresponding CSS:

```
.background {
    z-index: 1;
}
.background_img {
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
body
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.scroll {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm figured it out, it was the css code part `position:absolute`
that screwed me over